# it is possible to post parameters for register?

Tags: swift3, nsurlrequest

i try to use the URLRequest for post Parameters (user name  , password ) for some website from iOS (swift language) and the operation is success and i receive message success from the web which tell me you are logged in

below it's my code :

```
 // check the user name and password
        guard let url = URL(string: "http://MyWeb/login.php")else {
            displayAlertControllerForLogin(title: "Wrong URL", message: "Please Check URL")
            return
        }

        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
        urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
        let postString = "username=\(userName)&password=\(password)"
        urlRequest.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) {[weak self] (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("have an error")
                return
            }// end the if error

            let string = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)

            if let string = string {
            if string.contains("cel_song") {

                DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                    //  present main view for check only
                    let tabBarController = MainVC()
                    self?.present(tabBarController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }// end the dispatch

            }else{
                // show the alert if the user invalid
                DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                    self?.displayAlertControllerForLogin(title: "Error Login!", message: "Please Check User Name / Password")
                }// end the dispatch
            }// end the else
        }// end the if let string

     }// end the task
        task.resume()
```

now please i need to register to this web site through the post 5 parameters using URLrequest (username , full name ,email, website,password,confirmPassword) to register in that website
but the operation is failed 
the below is my code for register in website using urlRequest post :

```
guard let url = URL(string: "http://MyWeb/register.php") else {displayAlertControllerForLogin(title: "Wrong URL", message: "Please ReWrite URL") ; return }

            var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)

            urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
            let webSite = "google"
            let postString = "username=\(userName)&fullname=\(fullName)&email=\(email)&website=\(webSite)&password=\(password)&confirmPassword=\(confirmPassword)"

            urlRequest.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

           let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest, completionHandler: {[weak self] (data, response, error) in
            if let error = error {
                self?.displayAlertControllerForLogin(title: "Error Issue", message: error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }

            // fetch the data
            let string = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)
            if let string = string {
                if string.contains("Registration...") {
                    // register faield
                    DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                        self?.displayAlertControllerForLogin(title: "Register Faield!", message: "Some Issue Occur When Try To register!")
                        print(string)
                        return
                    }

                }else{

                    // register complete
                    DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                        self?.displayAlertControllerForLogin(title: "Register Complete!", message: "Welcome \(userName) You Are Register To Ampache Successfully!")
                        return
                    }
                }// end the if string.contains
            }// end the if let

           })// end the task
            task.resume()
```

my question please it's possible to register to some website using url request with post 5 parameters in swift language?

Comment: What is the actual response you get from your API?

Comment: without using API it is possible to make this operation?

Comment: I was asking for the `URLResponse` you get from the API you are calling,  namely _"http://MyWeb/register.php"_. Without seeing the actual error you receive, it is really hard to determine what might go wrong, since all APIs have their own expected request formats.

Comment: i get this response (<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x78e8a0> { URL: http://MyWeb/register.php } { status code: 200, headers {
    Connection = "Keep-Alive";
    "Content-Length" = 5023;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=UTF-8";
    Date = "Mon, 31 Jul 2017 12:25:11 GMT";
    "Keep-Alive" = "timeout=5, max=100";
    Server = "Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) PHP/5.4.16";
    "X-Powered-By" = "PHP/5.4.16";
} }
)

Comment: You get a successful response code, so why do you think your registration is unsuccessful? You should also include the parsed data object in your question, since your API might be returning the exact error message there.

Comment: yes i get the correct status code it is 200 but when i try to put my new user and password i get the user not registered and when i check my table in mariadb on centos7 i have no user like i put it when i register it

Comment: So you should be looking for the error in your API. Check if you can register using Postman to send the request, that will help you to decide if the error is in your API or if you are sending wrong information from your Swift code.

Comment: ok thank you very much i will check it with the Postman